# Best way to install Ubuntu 18.04 on Dell Precision 5530

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, system-installation, dell

I would like to install 18.04 LTS on my Dell Precision 5530 with following specs:

```
Intel Core i9-8950HK
32GB RAM
Quadro P2000
4k Screen 
Intel Wifi Link 9260 2x2.
```

I'm coming from Kubuntu 18.04 and had minor graphic issues, which always forced me to restart when I connected a screen. Since I do this daily it is quite annoying.

Do you might have any tips before I start the installation. 
SWAP partition or SWAP file (had this on Kubuntu)? 
Which driver to use for my NVidia card and how to install? 
Should I let the system install all drivers during installation our should I better do it myself afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Swap: See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq

2) Intel drivers, GPU & WiFi: The drivers are in the kernel.

3) Here are specific instructions for the P2000 proprietary drivers, which I suggest adding after standard installation completes: https://tutorialforlinux.com/2019/04/11/how-to-install-nvidia-quadro-p2000-ubuntu-18-04-driver/

4) Standard installation?  https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#0

Comment: Thanks a lot this is very helpful.